# Serial data type in sql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am using postgresql and I want to make a coloumn of data type 'serial' which will generate automatically (starting from 1000 and steps of 100).

Any help of how can I do it?

Comment: The same sequence as what ? Also, why is you question tagged with SQL-Server ? (SQL-Server is Microsoft DBMS)

Comment: are you asking for auto increment ID column that has custom increment steps and starting value?

Comment: hey
try this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html and this http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/database_guides/Practical_PostgreSQL_database/PostgreSQL_x14316_001.htm and http://www.java2s.com/Code/PostgreSQL/Sequence/Getnextsequencevalue.htm .. you can use sequence to increment the value, where you can specify the `start` value and also the `increment` in you case somthing like this `CREATE SEQUENCE my_id_seq START 1000 INCREMENT 100;`

Comment: @PresleyDias: linking to the docs of an obsolete version and to a book from 2002... not cool!

Comment: -1 for apparently not even trying to look this up in the manual

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL has very good documentation on this. You can create sequence:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html
and then create table with `SERIAL` column:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_table1_seq START 1000 INCREMENT 100;
CREATE TABLE table1 (id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('my_table1_seq'), txt varchar(1000));
INSERT INTO table1 (txt) VALUES ('zorro1');
INSERT INTO table1 (txt) VALUES ('zorro2');
INSERT INTO table1 (txt) VALUES ('zorro3');
SELECT * FROM table1;
```